# Php base base64 encode and decode not working correctly

Tags: php, string, decode, encode

I want to encode and decode in php using base64, but the encode and decode function does not give me correct output. I am using code from [online php functions](http://base64_encode.onlinephpfunctions.com/).

I encode this string

> "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد
>   كلمات العربي"

and get the output:

> "YmVzdCBhcmFiaWMgc29uZ3MgbG92ZXMgMjAxMyBub25zdG9wINij2YHYttmEINmF2YYg2KfZhNij2LrYp9mG2Yog2KfZhNit2Kgg2KfZhNis2K/ZitivINmD2YTZhdin2Kog2KfZhNi52LHYqNmK"

When I use this php code it does not give a correct encode and decode string:

```
    $str = 'best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي';
    $decodestr = base64_decode($str);

    echo 'decode = '.$decodestr

    $encodestr = base64_encode($decodestr );

    echo '<br>';
    echo 'encode = '.$encodestr;



    i got this output :

decode = më-j¶›‰Ë(ž%¢÷¬ÛMwž‰ì¶Š

encode = bestarabicsongsloves2013nonstoo=
```

Can any one help me with how I can get correct encode and decode string using base64 encode and decode function in php?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with base64 functions. You have simple error in code and you haven't set the page encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function base64_decode only decodes already base64encoded chunk .
In your code you are trying to base64decode a plain text which is causing issues.

**`<?php $str = 'best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي'; $encodestr = base64_encode($str); echo 'Base64 encoding of "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي" = '.'<br><br>'.$encodestr; $decodestr=base64_decode($encodestr); echo '<br><br><br>'; echo 'Base64 decoding of "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي" = '.'<br><br>'.$decodestr; ?>`**

Try this code: it works fine for me!

Comment: why so me output as Base64 encoding of "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop Ø£ÙØ¶Ù„ Ù…Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø£ØºØ§Ù†ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø­Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø¯ÙŠØ¯ ÙƒÙ„Ù…Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠ"  it is does not show me urdu languages alphabets

Comment: base64 encoding doesnt show urdu language's or any plain text when encoded. you can get back your urdu language letters when base64 decoding it .

Comment: my issue is if i print $str = 'best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي';

echo 'str='.$str;         i got output                                                     str=best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop Ø£ÙØ¶Ù„ Ù…Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø£ØºØ§Ù†ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø­Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ø¬Ø¯ÙŠØ¯ ÙƒÙ                                       i am not able to print urdu alphabet string in chrome browser .

Comment: same issue in firefox and IE

Comment: <?php
$str = 'best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي';

echo 'str='.$str;


$encodestr = base64_encode($str);
echo 'Base64 encoding of "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي" = '.'<br><br>'.$encodestr;
$decodestr=base64_decode($encodestr);
echo '<br><br><br>';
echo 'Base64 decoding of "best arabic songs loves 2013 nonstop أفضل من الأغاني الحب الجديد كلمات العربي" = '.'<br><br>'.$decodestr;
?>

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use this PHP to encode/decode your base64.**

```
<?php
/*To encode A string into base64 in PHP: */
$str = "I am Krypton-X"; /*This is your string*/
$encode = base64_encode($str); /*Encode*/
echo("$encode"); /*print base64*/
?>
```

*To decode base64 into string in PHP*

```
<?php
$base = "SSBhbSBLcnlwdG9uLVg=";
/*Your base64 encoded data */
$decode = base64_decode($base); /*Decode*/
echo("$decode"); /* print string */
?>
```